# Return inserted id with TypeORM & NestJS raw query: await connection.manager.query(`INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, typescript, mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm looking to return the id or better yet, all information that was inserted, using a raw query with TypeORM and NestJS. Example as follows:

```
await connection.manager.query(`INSERT INTO...`)
```

When assigning the query to a constant and console logging it below, it does not yield any helpful information:

```
OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 1,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningCount: 1,
    message: '',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0
}
```

As you can see, it returns no pertinent information, the `insertId` above is obviously incorrect, and it returns this every time, regardless of the actual parameters of the query.

I know with more typical TypeORM queries you can use `.return(['name_of_column_you_want_returned']).execute()`
and it will return the relevant information just fine. Is there any way to do this with a raw query? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr You're getting the raw mariadb driver response (OkPacket) from the INSERT command, and you'd need a new SELECT query to see the data.

---

You're using the [TypeORM EntityManager](https://typeorm.io/#/entity-manager-api), and the docs don't mention a return value. [Looking at the source code for query](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L154), the return type is `any`. Since it's a raw query, it probably returns an object based on the type of database you're using rather than having a standard format.

In this case, you're using MariaDb, which returned an `OkPacket`. Here's the documentation:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ok_packet/